# Check if Bot and Member are in the same channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I cant really figure out how to do this without iterating through all voicechannels and compare the user ids, but this is veeeery slow. Is there a better way? I want to know this, because my Music Bot should add a song to the queue if the User who wrote the command is in the same voice channel as the Bot

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ctx.guild.voice_client.channel == ctx.message.author.voice.channel):
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Member.voice`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20voice#discord.Member.voice) and [`VoiceState.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voicestate%20channel#discord.VoiceState.channel) to get the current voice state of both the bot & the person that wrote it (`ctx.author`) to get the channels immediately without having to loop through anything. `Voice` returns `None` if they aren't currently in a `VoiceChannel`.